# rubygems' Could not find gem > 'win32console (>= 0, runtime)'

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install the sample app located here: http://jhollingworth.com/2010/12/26/web-automation-using-cucumber-capybara/

One of the initial steps for setting this up are running bundle in the install location. When I execute bundle I get the following error:

> C:\Capybara\jhollingworth-.Net-Web-Automation-example>bundle
>   Your Gemfile doesn't have any sources.
>   You can add one with a line like
>   'source :rubygems' Could not find gem
>   'win32console (>= 0, runtime)' in any
>   of the gem sources listed in your
>   Gemfile.

When I check the bundle Gemfile it does have  "http://rubygems.org" included

Can anyone shed some light on the above. Google return similar results but for different packages (e.g sql)

My GemFile currently contains : 
source "rubygems.org"; Is that the right format?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your gemfile doesn't have any sources listed. Add 'source :rubygems' to the top of your Gemfile. If that doesn't solve your problem, post the contents of your Gemfile.

Comment: Looking at [the Gemfile manpage](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html#SOURCES-source-), I would recommend changing it to 'source "http://rubygems.org"' or 'source :rubygems'.